# jQuery webcam plugin and flash webcam permissions

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-webcam-plugin

I'm using this jQuery plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

When I run this code on `localhost`, I never see the flash permissions request to access the webcam.  If I specifically set flash to allow webcam access to `localhost`, the plugin works.

What step am I missing to cause this plugin to request permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used the above mentioned plugin, but could it be that you are setting the width and height to a smaller value than 214x137? That is the size that is needed for the permissions dialog. When your Flash file is smaller than that, it just won't appear.

A solution to that is resizing the component after access has been granted or denied. Although I do not know whether or not that works with the jquery plugin.

Comment: I am setting the size to 200x200, so that may be it.  I'll try increasing it and see what happens; thanks!

Comment: At least that will improve it!

Comment: Unfortunately, increasing the size didn't help(though I'm leaving it increased to show the full confirm dialog when it is working).

Comment: This problem ended up being a corrupt swf file from using the plugin's make script.  Solved it by switching to a different plugin.  Marking this as the answer since I did want a window bigger than 200x200 for the reason listed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have flash add-on enabled on your browser..^_^